# A triangle has a side of $8$ opposite an angle of $120^\circ$. The other sides are $x$ and $2x$. Find $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We have the following triangle:

[image]

I have tried using the tan trigonometric propriety. By using the following relationship : tan 120 = adjacent/opposite and I get a negative result. When I do tan 180-120 = tan 60 get x = 4.61 which means the 2x = 9.22 which seems to be wrong because the 8 cm side is supposed to be the longest.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This property of $\tan$ only applies to right triangles

Comment: What should I do instead?

Comment: I would suggest utilizing the laws of sines and cosines. You can find information on them quite easily online.

Answer (score 1):

By law of cosines $8^2 = x^2 + (2x)^2 - 2(x)(2x)\cos(120)$. From here you can solve for $x$.

Comment: it gives me x = 3. Just to be sure is it correct?

Comment: That's not correct. How about you edit the question body to show what you have tried?